# Алгоритм вращения 3d куба

Tags: алгоритм, анимация, 3d, случайные-числа

Делаю настольную игру, где хорошо бы было реализовать бросок кубиков. Пока что я сделал обычный генератор чисел от 1 до 6. Разобрался как сделать 3d куб и вращать его с помощью событий от нажатия  на стрелки. Понимаю, как написать js-функцию, которая будет изменять свойства этого куба и, например вращать его в любой плоскости.
[Есть реализация кубика](https://youtu.be/fmSIHr3WKxk)

Однако не могу придумать, как запрограммировать вращение, чтобы оно было более естественным и останавливалось на нужном мне сгенерированном числе (чтобы оно было не всегда в одну сторону хотя бы).
В ответе хотел бы прочитать какие-нибудь идеи, возможно псевдокод, алгоритм, как заставить кубик крутится более естественно.
Хотел бы достигнуть такого результата, как на сайте [бросок костей онлайн](https://ru.piliapp.com/random/dice/).
Или, может, можно использовать api кубиков?

Comment: Решение задачи ещё нужно?